# How can I delete before and after EMAIL in notepad++?

Tags: email, notepad++, find-and-replace, string

**I have this:**

```
:814, 'pera', 'name1@gmail.com', '2ed', '', 'da', 0.00, '195..110.18'),

>815, 'danka', 'name2@gmail.com', 'd3d6', '0655566', 'da', 0.00, '212..65.82'),

*816, 'ana', 'name3@gmail.com', 'b6e1', '06rt45t02', 'da', 0.00, '178..83.40'),

/817, 'biljana', 'name4@gmail.com', '53c9', '', 'da', 0.00, '95.180.6.'),

,818, 'Vladimir', 'nemae5@gmail.com', '02', '', 'da', 0.00, '178..29.221'),
```

**I Need this:**

```
name1@gmail.com

name2@gmail.com

name3@gmail.com

name4@gmail.com

name5@gmail.com
```

I need a string for notepad++ to replace everything before and after an email address

Note: Everything after and before an email is different. Not one line of code is the same.
Some have just numbers (no `,` and no `'`), some both, some have just after email text, some are the same as the row before

Comment: What have you tried? Super User is not a script writing service. We will be more than happy to help, if you show some research effort. As it stands, this question will be likely closed.

Comment: The output looks like a simple CSV format to me. Have you tried importing it into a spreadsheet program like Excel? Once you do that, column C should be just the e-mail addresses - except perhaps for the case of "Vladimir". Stuff like that (an extra comma outside of quotation marks) will throw it off for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex replace

search:

```
^.*'(.*@.*\.\w{1,6})',.*$
```

Or

```
^.*\W(\w*@\w*.\w*)\W.*$
```

Replace:

```
$1
```

Feel free to enhance the regex if you want, I know it's not perfect

Edit: another regex to try